# How to capture values created in emit() method call in python logging?

Tags: python, flask, logging

We are currently using our own GitHubHandler class that we are adding to our default python logging using the `addHandler` method. This GitHubHandler class has an `emit` method where we call the GitHub API to create a new github issue for our repo. This API call returns all the data we need around the newly created issue, but we would like to grab this issue number and be able to return it to the front end when an error occurs as part of the error message.

From what I can tell, there is no way to return the value up through the logging methods to a place where I could grab it in our code and send it anywhere useful.

Are there any good strategies for grabbing data only available in the emit methods of loggers?

Our backend is python/flask using python 3.11 in case that's helpful.

Comment: See [ask]. It's unclear and unspecific. Define the problem, try to implement stub code, and post a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

The flask g object is one of the flask context local variable that can be used to store information for the duration of the request context. If you store your GitHub issue number here from within your logging code it will be accessible later when you are returning your error message to the front end.